# Canceling an internship after accepting offer

Tags: software-industry, united-states, internship

I accepted an internship offer this summer after a brief - too brief, I now realize - conversation with a manager. After talking to her again about project specifics I now see that this company is not the right environment for me at all, and I would much rather spend the summer working on my own projects. How bad would it be to cancel the internship? Does anyone have any advice on how to do so gracefully?

Comment: So, you haven't started yet? Have you signed some contract or similar already?

Comment: Haven't started yet - it is around a month away - and I did sign an offer letter.

Comment: Do your long term goals consist of you working for yourself or for a company?

Answer (score 7):

> How bad would it be to cancel the internship? Does anyone have any advice on how to do so gracefully?

It depends on the relationship you have with the organization. It will not be positive but it also is not unexpected. The earlier you tell them the longer it gives them to find a replacement. Be concise, conciliatory and honest.

Taking a step back, you state it "is not the right environment for me at all, and I would much rather spend the summer working on my own projects". However, there are many good reasons to still accept. Working in a corporate environment on real-world projects, timely references/referees and increasing your breadth of knowledge and experience are all good reasons to do an internship. Your side projects are still there for weeknights or weekends.

Comment: +1 for 'many good reasons to still accept'. Internships are a good time to find out where you don't want to be, and why it is important to get as much as possible out of your education. Usually you will have only 1 or 2 weeks to work after you write to them to quit during your probation, he should give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

**It’s fine to rescind your acceptance and unlikely that you’re “burning a bridge.”**

**Call the hiring manager soon and offer an honest explanation.** Lead with something like:

> “I’m calling to let you know I have decided against joining ____ for the summer. After considering the role carefully, I’ve realized this isn’t the best role for me right now. ...”

Make it clear that your decision is final and you are not trying to negotiate a better offer — you are simply no longer interested in the job.

Following your call, **make it extra clear you won’t be taking the position by sending an email to the hiring manager and recruiter.** Be brief.

You need not apologize in your communication - accepting and later declining a job is not uncommon and is entirely okay if done politely and with respect for the individuals who attempted to recruit you. However, it would also be just fine to apologize for any mis-communication or mis-understanding on your part, if you feel so compelled.

Best of luck in a different role. I’m very glad you had your realization about the role before starting work.